# chrome Extension : Set persistent cookie in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working with chrome extension development here I need to set cookie value by my extension.

I have set cookies by:

```
chrome.cookies.set({ url: "http://example.com/", name: "CookieVar", value: "123" });
```

But it available in the current browser when I close the browser data was lost so that I go with

```
chrome.cookies.set({ url: "http://example.com/", name: "CookieVar", value: "123", expirationDate: 3600 });
```

But from this I am not able to see cookie information is anything I have missed here.

Comment: Do you have the permission set in `manifest.json` per [this documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/cookies.html)?

Comment: Yes I have done that.....cookies is work fine if I haven't set expiration Date....

Comment: Add above code in background.js then only it will work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that your expiration date is `1 Jan 1970 01:00` (3600 equals 1 hour after UNIX epoch). So of course your cookie will be deleted because it's expiration date is set to the past.

You need to provide appropriate expirationDate for your cookie. In [documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/cookies.html), `expirationDate` defined as:

> The expiration date of the cookie as the number of seconds since the
> UNIX epoch

To set a cookie relative to the current time you need to add seconds to `(new Date().getTime() / 1000)` as @pickled suggested.

Comment: I have gone with : chrome.cookies.set({ url: "http://example.com/", name: "CookieVar", value: "123", expirationDate: 3600 });                then also it won't work for me

Comment: Berk's comment still stands then; you've set your expiry time for one hour after the epoch, or `1 Jan 1970, 1:00:00 AM GMT`.

Comment: @Jimmy Sawczuk  sorry  I am not able to get your point please explain me. According to http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/cookies.html I have to pass integer value which I have done in code

Comment: The issue is that you're assuming the integer is relative to when you set the cookie; it's not. So to set the expiration date to an hour from now, you'd need to set it to `<now_timestamp> + 3600`, or, `1313506823 + 3600` if I were to set the cookie right now.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't set a value for expirationDate then the cookie will expire when the user closes the browser.

If you do set a value then it must be the current time + how many seconds until it expires.
For example:

```
{expirationDate: (new Date().getTime()/1000) + 3600}
```

would set it as the current time, plus 3600 seconds, so an hour in the future.

You were setting it as 3600 past the base UNIX time, which is the start of 1970, so it immediately expired.